# ssh: Could not resolve hostname ubuntu: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I am trying to implement a ssh config file. It was working with a different ec2 instance moments ago, so I am not sure what is different here. I can `ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntun@ipaddress` just fine but when I use my config file `ssh ubuntu` I get the following error

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/anders/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ubuntu: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

My Config looks like the following

```
Host fsdfs.compute.amazonaws.com
User ubuntu
Port 22
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/fds-fds-dsfs.pem
```

When I run ls -ld on .ssh I get
`drwx------ 2 anders anders 4096 May 26 06:45 /home/anders/.ssh`

When I run ls -ld on .ssh/config I get
`-rw------- 1 anders anders 137 May 26 06:26 /home/anders/.ssh/config`

Hopefully someone can help with this. Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up working for me, unless someone has a answer why mine didn't work this is the solution

```
Host ubuntu  
  HostName fsdf.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  User ubuntu
  Port 22
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/fds-dfas-fdsa.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below configuration in the '*config*' file

```
Host *
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Location of config file is '*~/.ssh/config*'

Then do *ssh hostname2* from instance-1 and you can able to connect from instance-1 to instance-2.

Here, *hostname2* will be the hostname configured in instance-2 in the location '*vim /etc/hosts*'